# Python- How to change lists order in a list of lists

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of lists that i want to put in order with the times that a person leaves he's job. I already made a code to give me only the time but i need something to check the times and put them in order.

```
inFile=removeHeader(file_name) # the information is taken from a txt file and this only gives me the part of the services
#print inFile gives me list of lists like [['Peter', ' 06-CB-89', ' Xavier', ' 09:45', ' 10:15', ' downtown', ' 10', ' standby'], ['Robert', ' 13-KI-54', ' Paul', ' 09:30', ' 10:30', ' Castle', ' 45', ' standby']

for time in inFile:
    hours=time[4]

    print hours  #this gives me only the hours they left work
```

Answer (score -1):

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

you have to sort the main list by the leave time i.e. the 5th value of the sublists, the key argument of sorted alows you to specify a function that will  be called to compute keys the list is sorted based on:

```
import time
x =[['Peter', ' 06-CB-89', ' Xavier', ' 09:45', ' 10:15', ' downtown', ' 10', ' standby'], ['Robert', ' 13-KI-54', ' Paul', ' 09:30', ' 10:30', ' Castle', ' 45', ' standby']]
sorted(x, key = lambda x: x[4])
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.